# Error while exporting to excel

Tags: model-view-controller, closedxml

My export to excel controller code is

```
 [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult ExporttoExcel(Domain obj, int table)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = Domain.GetAllTables();
        if (ds != null)
        {
            if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
                {
                    var wsreport = wb.Worksheets.Add(ds.Tables[table], "Renewals");
                    wsreport.Tables.SingleOrDefault().ShowAutoFilter = false;

                    Response.ClearContent();
                    Response.Buffer = true;
                    Response.Charset = "";
                    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

                    if (table == 0)
                    {
                        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.xls", "Renewals-Current Month"));
                    }
                    else if (table == 1)
                    {
                        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.xls", "Renewals-Next Month"));
                    }

                    using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                        MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                        Response.Flush();                          
                    }
                    Response.End();
                }
            }
        }
        return View("ViewDomain");
    }
```

Namespaces included:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using dsmanager.Models;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using dsmanager.DLL;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Drawing;
using ClosedXML.Excel;
```

I am getting the following error[image]

How can this error be solved. what references are missing?
All the nugget packages installed are updated and are of the latest version. 
How can the assembly be loaded

Comment: What version of ClosedXML?

Comment: ClosedXml installed version 0.87.1

Answer (score 0):

You probably have `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` version 2.7 or higher, which is incompatible with `ClosedXML` v0.87.1. Upgrade to `ClosedXML` v0.88 or higher.